# Reduce code redundancy in JS [Angular JS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with a angular application and i have the following functions.

**Function 1**

```
   vm.getInfo = function () {
        var infoKey = "INFO1";
        var url = "www.example.com" + InfoKey;
        return datacontext.getData(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return vm.infoResponse = response.data.texts;
            });
    }
    vm.getInfo();
```

**Function 2**

```
     vm.getDetails = function () {
        var infoKey = "INFO2";
        var url = "www.example.com" + InfoKey;
        return datacontext.getData(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return vm.detailsResponse = response.data.texts;
            });
    }
    vm.getDetails();
```

Both the above functions have similar behavior, but only the *infoKey* and the return value changes. Right now i have written the functions like this. This might sound very silly, but how can i optimize this function to reduce the code redundancy.

Comment: Make things that are *variable* (e.g, `infoKey`) a *parameter* of the function. Consider to perform operations such as assigning to `vm.x` at the *callsite* rather than inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make a common function that accept infoKey and then only return the response.data.texts and Handel the VM variable at the call back function.

Comment: function getDetails(InfoKey) {
        var url = "www.example.com" + InfoKey;
        return datacontext.getData(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data.texts;
            });
    }

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to provide Moreno information. Comments are not a good place for code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things -

1) Get `infoKey` as parameter & return `response.data.texts`-

```
function get(infoKey) {
    var url = "www.example.com" + InfoKey;
    return datacontext.getData(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data.texts;
        });
}
```

2) Pass callable function as parameter to handle response -

```
function get(infoKey, handleResponse) {
    var url = "www.example.com" + InfoKey;
    return datacontext.getData(url)
        .then(handleResponse);
}
```

Using it like this -

```
get('Infokey1', function onResponse(response) {
   vm.infoResponse = response.data.texts;
})
```

Comment: You can pass `handleResponse` directly to `then`. There is no need for another function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInfo(infoKey) {
    var url = "www.example.com" + infoKey;
    var promise = datacontext.getData(url);
    return promise;
}
```

Calling function should do something like:

```
getInfo(infoKey).then((response)=> {
                vm.detailsResponse = response.data.texts;
            },(err)=>{
                //Handle errors here.
            });
```

Or, you could simply send a callback to the getInfo function and handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 vm.getDetails = function (infoKey) {
    var url = "www.example.com" + infoKey;
    return datacontext.getData(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            if(infoKey=="INFO1"){return vm.infoResponse = response.data.texts;}
            else{ return vm.detailsResponse = response.data.texts;}
        });
}
vm.getDetails(infoKey);
```

hope this help you.